# After requesting the image in html, three.js requests the same image again

Tags: javascript, html, performance, three.js, request

This is code

```js
let texture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load("http://odf9m3avc.bkt.clouddn.com/1493817789932.jpg")
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/88/three.min.js"></script>
<img class='preLoad' src = 'http://odf9m3avc.bkt.clouddn.com/1493817789932.jpg' style='display:none'>
```

[image: img]

I want the browser to load the image when parsing the html, rather than waiting for the three.js initialization and then request image.

for example

```js
// this image only request once,other img tags use it directly
```

```html
<img src='http://odf9m3avc.bkt.clouddn.com/1493817789932.jpg'>
<img src='http://odf9m3avc.bkt.clouddn.com/1493817789932.jpg'>
<img src='http://odf9m3avc.bkt.clouddn.com/1493817789932.jpg'>
```

but why three.js request it instead of use it directly

It is a waste of time.
How can I solve it?
thanks！

Comment: Are you loading the texture in `document.onload`? I.e. after the browser has finished loading everything else?

Comment: The problem is unreproducable. I checked your example and html loads `image` before `three.js`

Comment: @ChrisG yes,i use react.js set my script at the end of <body>

Comment: @KrzysztofJaniszewski my code in snippet can always recurrent,you can run snippet, open Developer Tools - Network. and same img will load twice.

Comment: @YuriTu yes it is loaded twice, but you wrote *`I want the browser to load the image when parsing the html, rather than waiting for the three.js initialization and then request image.`* it is happening already and then later three.js loads it second time. SO you would want htree.js not to load image if it is already loaded?

Comment: code in the snippet  is an example, I abstracted the problem.

Comment: @KrzysztofJaniszewski yes,I think after my first request, the browser will generate a cache of the image. Second request will load cache. three.js should load image instead of request

Comment: @KrzysztofJaniszewski   for example, your html file has many <img src='xxx''> .they has same 'src'.but this image only request on once.Same reasoning in my example I already requested this image ,but why three.js request this image again.

Comment: three.js should use it directly

Comment: What is the actual problem you're trying to solve? Why not preload the image using JS, and pass it directly to three.js?

Comment: @ChrisG if I preload image in HTML,I don't have to wait for JS to download then request image and wait it.   When the js file is loaded, three.js can use it directly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this,

Create the `img` element with an id like this,

```
<img src="YOUR_URL" id="preloaded-image">
```

After your page is loaded, you can get this element by,

```
var picture = document.getElementById( 'preloaded-image' );
```

Now create a three.js texture using this image,

```
var texture = new THREE.Texture();
texture.image = picture;
texture.needsUpdate = true;
```

Now you can use this texture. I hope it will not request the file again(I haven't tested it)

Comment: Amazing!you are right ! could you tell me the principle?